# How i can wrap up different group of elements in one element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

How wrap different elements in one root element using xslt

My XML Code is:

```
<section>
<body>
<p>Trying text</p>
<Head>Heading 1</Head>
  <ListItem1>item 1</ListItem1>
  <ListItem2>item 2</ListItem2>
  <ListItem2>item 3</ListItem2>
  <ListItem3>item 4</ListItem3>
  <ListItem4>item 4</ListItem4>
  <ListItem1>item 1</ListItem1>
  <ListItem2>item 2</ListItem2>
  <ListItem2>item 3</ListItem2>
  <ListItem3>item 4</ListItem3>
  <ListItem3>item 4</ListItem3>
  <ListItem4>item 4</ListItem4>
  <ListItem3>item 4</ListItem3>
  <ListItem1>item 1</ListItem1>
  <ListItem2>item 2</ListItem2>
  <ListItem2>item 3</ListItem2>
  <ListItem3>item 4</ListItem3>
  <ListItem3>item 4</ListItem3>
  <ListItem2>item 2</ListItem2>
  <ListItem2>item 3</ListItem2>
<Head>Heading 2</Head>
  <ListItem1>item 1</ListItem1>
  <ListItem2>item 2</ListItem2>
  <ListItem2>item 3</ListItem2>
  <ListItem3>item 4</ListItem3>
  <ListItem1>item 1</ListItem1>
  <ListItem2>item 2</ListItem2>
  <ListItem2>item 3</ListItem2>
  <ListItem3>item 4</ListItem3>
  <ListItem1>item 1</ListItem1>
  <ListItem2>item 2</ListItem2>
  <ListItem2>item 3</ListItem2>
  <ListItem3>item 4</ListItem3>
  <ListItem3>item 4</ListItem3>
  <ListItem2>item 2</ListItem2>
  <ListItem2>item 3</ListItem2>
</body>
</section>
```

XSLT I am using:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Section">
  <Section>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </Section>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ListItem1">
        <div>
            <title><xsl:call-template name="ListItem"/></title>
        </div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()
                                      [not(self::ListItem1|ListItem2)][1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output need as:

Wrapping listitem1,2,3,4 in one root element and heading to heading in one root element

```
<Notes>
<p>Trying text</p>
<div>
<title>Heading 1</title>
<entry>
  <primary>item 1</primary>
  <secondary>item 2</secondary>
  <secondary>item 3</secondary>
  <teritary level="1">item 4</teritary>
  <teritary level="2">item 4</teritary>
</entry>
<entry>
  <primary>item 1</primary>
  <secondary>item 2</secondary>
  <secondary>item 3</secondary>
  <teritary level="1">item 4</teritary>
  <teritary level="1">item 4</teritary>
  <teritary level="2">item 4</teritary>
  <teritary level="1">item 4</teritary>
</entry>
<entry>
  <primary>item 1</primary>
  <secondary>item 2</secondary>
  <secondary>item 3</secondary>
  <teritary level="1">item 4</teritary>
  <teritary level="1">item 4</teritary>
  <secondary>item 2</secondary>
  <secondary>item 3</secondary>
</entry>
</div>
<div>
<title>Heading 2</title>
<entry>
  <primary>item 1</primary>
  <secondary>item 2</secondary>
  <secondary>item 3</secondary>
  <teritary level="1">item 4</teritary>
</entry>
<entry>
  <primary>item 1</primary>
  <secondary>item 2</secondary>
  <secondary>item 3</secondary>
  <teritary level="1">item 4</teritary>
</entry>
<entry>
  <primary>item 1</primary>
  <secondary>item 2</secondary>
  <secondary>item 3</secondary>
  <teritary level="1">item 4</teritary>
  <teritary level="1">item 4</teritary>
  <secondary>item 2</secondary>
  <secondary>item 3</secondary>
</entry>
</div>
</Notes>
```

Please Assist me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your stylesheet says `version="1.0"` but uses `copy-namespaces="no"` which is an XSLT 2.0 construct. So please clarify whether you use XSLT 2.0 or 1.0.

Comment: I am using XSLT2.0 only @Martin Honnen

Comment: Can you explain that mapping from `ListItemX` elements to `primary`, `secondary`, ... elements? How does that work? When do you need to introduce a `level` attribute?

Comment: If ListItem1 started means we want add root tag 'entry' them 'primary', 'secondary', teritary' values move to inside 'entry' again whereever primary element started before 'entry' have to be closed then entry have to be start, and level attribute need from 'teritiary' element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a stylesheet doing the wrapping (both `div` and `entry`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="Head">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="self::Head">
                        <div>
                            <title>
                                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                            </title>
                            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group() except ." group-starting-with="ListItem1">
                                <entry>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                                </entry>
                            </xsl:for-each-group>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ListItem1">
        <primary>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </primary>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ListItem2">
        <secondary>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </secondary>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ListItem3 | ListItem4">
        <tertiary>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tertiary>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<section>
   <p>Trying text</p>
   <div>
      <title>Heading 1</title>
      <entry>
         <primary>item 1</primary>
         <secondary>item 2</secondary>
         <secondary>item 3</secondary>
         <tertiary>item 4</tertiary>
         <tertiary>item 4</tertiary>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <primary>item 1</primary>
         <secondary>item 2</secondary>
         <secondary>item 3</secondary>
         <tertiary>item 4</tertiary>
         <tertiary>item 4</tertiary>
         <tertiary>item 4</tertiary>
         <tertiary>item 4</tertiary>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <primary>item 1</primary>
         <secondary>item 2</secondary>
         <secondary>item 3</secondary>
         <tertiary>item 4</tertiary>
         <tertiary>item 4</tertiary>
         <secondary>item 2</secondary>
         <secondary>item 3</secondary>
      </entry>
   </div>
   <div>
      <title>Heading 2</title>
      <entry>
         <primary>item 1</primary>
         <secondary>item 2</secondary>
         <secondary>item 3</secondary>
         <tertiary>item 4</tertiary>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <primary>item 1</primary>
         <secondary>item 2</secondary>
         <secondary>item 3</secondary>
         <tertiary>item 4</tertiary>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <primary>item 1</primary>
         <secondary>item 2</secondary>
         <secondary>item 3</secondary>
         <tertiary>item 4</tertiary>
         <tertiary>item 4</tertiary>
         <secondary>item 2</secondary>
         <secondary>item 3</secondary>
      </entry>
   </div>
</section>
```

I haven't so far seen a clear explanation where the `level` attribute comes from or which are the rules to add it to which elements exactly, it seems using

```
<xsl:template match="ListItem3">
    <tertiary level="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tertiary>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ListItem4">
    <tertiary level="2">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tertiary>
</xsl:template>
```

instead of

```
    <xsl:template match="ListItem3 | ListItem4">
        <tertiary>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </tertiary>
    </xsl:template>
```

gives the right result for your sample.

Comment: with out root element 'section' how we can get

Comment: Thank you @Martin Honnen but root element section no need in out put

Comment: Please see my edited question in input added body element and output without  body element and section element as Notes

Comment: I am going to leave the answer as it is, adapt it yourself to your ever changing needs.

Comment: I have tried in different ways by adding 'except body' in <xsl:for-each-group select="* except body" group-starting-with="ListItem1"> but its not removing body element in output xml please give me on this small suggestion